# Python 3 gives wrong output when dividing two large numbers?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
a = 15511210043330985984000000  # (25!)
b = 479001600                   # (12!)
c = 6227020800                  # (13!)
```

On dividing `ans = int(a/(b*c))` or `ans = int((a/b)/c)` we get `ans` equal to `5200299` instead of `5200300`

Comment: check out [PEP 238](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/)

Comment: `(int)(some_expression) is NOT valid Python syntax. When asking a question, please take the (very slight) bother to show the code that you have actually run.

Comment: Sure it's valid Python syntax.

Comment: OK, it's accidentally valid syntax and not valid attitude. E.g. (int)a won't "work".

Comment: @JohnMachin if you're in the habit of wrapping expressions in extra parentheses it could work.  `(int)a` doesn't work, but `(int)(a)` does the right thing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Python 3.x `/` means floating point division and can give small rounding errors. Use `//` for integer division.

```
ans = a // (b*c)
```

Answer (score 4):

Try using integer division instead of float division.

```
>>> 15511210043330985984000000 / (479001600 * 6227020800)
5200299.999999999
>>> 15511210043330985984000000 // (479001600 * 6227020800)
5200300
```

Answer (score 3):

Your problem (not using integer arithmetic) has been swept under your carpet for you by Python 3.2:

```
Python 3.2 (r32:88445, Feb 20 2011, 21:29:02) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 15511210043330985984000000 / (479001600 * 6227020800)
5200300.0
>>> repr(15511210043330985984000000 / (479001600 * 6227020800))
'5200300.0'
>>> int(15511210043330985984000000 / (479001600 * 6227020800))
5200300

Python 3.1.3 (r313:86834, Nov 27 2010, 18:30:53) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 15511210043330985984000000 / (479001600 * 6227020800)
5200299.999999999
>>> repr(15511210043330985984000000 / (479001600 * 6227020800))
'5200299.999999999'
>>> int(15511210043330985984000000 / (479001600 * 6227020800))
5200299
```

I'm puzzled: presumably you used `int()` because you realised that it was producing a `float` answer. Why did you not take the (obvious?) next step of rounding it, e.g.

```
[3.1.3]
>>> int(round(15511210043330985984000000 / (479001600 * 6227020800)))
5200300
```

?